# Why MySQL doesn't use indexes in view with union select?

Tags: mysql, index, view, union

I've created a view:

```
create view dh_hits_new_all_old
as
select * from dh_hits_new_201806
union all
select * from dh_hits_new_201807;
```

When I select something with a where clause containing a field which has an index on the individual tables, MySQL doesn't use any indexes. See the explain outputs:

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from dh_hits_new_201806 where id_hits_url = 130442;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys               | key                         | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dh_hits_new_201806 | NULL       | ref  | dh_idx-hits_new-id_hits_url | dh_idx-hits_new-id_hits_url | 4       | const | 4453 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from dh_hits_new_201807 where id_hits_url = 130442;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys               | key                         | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dh_hits_new_201807 | NULL       | ref  | dh_idx-hits_new-id_hits_url | dh_idx-hits_new-id_hits_url | 4       | const | 4009 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> explain select count(*) from dh_hits_new_all_old where id_hits_url = 130442;
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table              | partitions | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>         | NULL       | ref  | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 4       | const |    10 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | dh_hits_new_201806 | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  | 65658 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  3 | UNION       | dh_hits_new_201807 | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  | 61552 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)
```

I do not understand why. This behavior is reflected of course also in the execution times:

```
mysql> select count(*) from dh_hits_new_201806 where id_hits_url = 130442;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     4453 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from dh_hits_new_201807 where id_hits_url = 130442;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     4009 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from dh_hits_new_all_old where id_hits_url = 130442;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     8462 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2,33 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a kind of bug in the old MySQL version. `UNION` effect using indexes.

In the versions older than the 5.7.3 version of MySQL, `UNION` statement works with a temporary table. It means, first of all, your data move to the temporary table and read them from the temporary table before that implement filtering.

> The server no longer uses a temporary table for UNION statements that
> meet certain qualifications. Instead, it retains from temporary table
> creation only the data structures necessary to perform result column
> typecasting. The table is not fully instantiated and no rows are
> written to or read from it; rows are sent directly to the client. The
> result is reduced memory and disk requirements, and smaller delay
> before the first row is sent to the client because the server need not
> wait until the last query block is executed. EXPLAIN and optimizer
> trace output will change: The UNION RESULT query block will not be
> present because that block is the part that reads from the temporary
> table.

Check out [version 5.7.3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-3.html) optimizer fixes.

Comment: I'm using a never version, 5.7.32 on Ubuntu 16 now. However it was also newer before (5.7.27). This is not the problem.

Comment: @TiborNagy - I agree.  _That_ improvement in `UNION` has only a small impact on _your_ query, and probably no impact on optimizing queries involving `VIEWs`.l

Comment: A missing optimization is not a bug though.

Answer (score 0):

`VIEWs` are syntactic sugar.  They probably never improve performance and sometimes hurt performance.

Your query is effectively:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        select * from dh_hits_new_201806
        union all
        select * from dh_hits_new_201807
         ) AS x
    WHERE id_hits_url = 130442;
```

The Optimizer is not very smart; it cannot transform that into this, which would run faster:

```
SELECT
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)  from dh_hits_new_201806 WHERE id_hits_url = 130442 ) +
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)  from dh_hits_new_201807 WHERE id_hits_url = 130442 );
```

Perhaps a better solution is to avoid the clumsy pattern wherein you have multiple tables that logically combine to make a single one.  That is, have only one table `dh_hits_new`.  Optionally, that table could be partitioned.  But, again, do not expect performance gains -- except for deleting 'old' data via `DROP PARTITION`.

Comment: Yes, of course I know, that to query the individual tables could be a solution. However to select `count(*)` was only an example to demonstrate the behavior and the individual tables are not usable if the query is embedded into a data provider in a framework to perform sorting and paging. As I see, I have to go back to use only 1 really huge archive table.

Comment: @TiborNagy - Write a feature request (bugs.mysql.com) requesting enhancements Views of Unions -- to push the outside Where clause into the individual Selects.

Comment: @TiborNagy - We can discuss (in a differently-focused Question) how to deal with "huge archive tables" and "Summary tables" and "Data Wherehousing" in general.  Here is some general reading:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse